# Discord.py bot command issue

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm facing with an issue at my discord bot. The command are not working. I think the code is not a problem. Everything works perfect except for the command. On discord, if I use !test *mytexthere*, nothing happens.

Thank you in advance!

```
 import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time
import random
from PIL import Image
token=('MyToken')

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))



@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)



client.run(token)
```

Comment: Do you want client or bot? You're mixing them (notice how you run the CLIENT but decorated the command with BOT). Remove the client and just use the bot.

Comment: BrainDead's answer is correct, you using both client and bot at the same time. You should get rid of  `client = discord.Client()` and leave the bot. Then change both `@client.event` and `client.run(token)` to `@bot.event` and `bot.run(token)`